# Get contents of a Var where part of line matches search string C#

Tags: c#, csv

I am reading a couple of csv files into var's as follows:

```
var myFullCsv = ReadFile(myFullCsvFilePath);
var masterCsv = ReadFile(csvFilePath);
```

Some of the line entries in each csv appear in both files and I am able to create a new var containing lines that exists in myFullCsv but not in masterCsv as follows:

```
var extraFilesCsv = myFullCsv.Except(masterCsv);
```

This is great because its very simple. However, I now wish to identify lines in myFullCsv where a specific string appears in the line. The string will correspond to one column of the csv data. I know that I can do this by reading each line of the var and splitting it up, then comparing the field I'm interested in to the string that I am searching for. However, this seems like a very long and inefficient approach as compared to my code above using the 'Except' command.
Is there some way that I can get the lines from myFullCsv with a very simple command or will I have to do it the long way? Please don't ask me to show the long way as that's what I am trying to avoid having to code although I can do it.

Sample csv data:

```
07801.jpg,67466,9452d316,\Folder1\FolderA\,
07802.jpg,78115,e50492d8,\Folder1\FolderB\,
07803.jpg,41486,37b6a100,\Folder1\FolderC\,
07804.jpg,93500,acdffc2b,\Folder2\FolderA\,
07805.jpg,67466,9452d316,\Folder2\FolderB\,
```

Sample desired output (I'm always looking for the entry in the 3rd column to match a string, in this case 9452d316):

```
07801.jpg,67466,9452d316,\Folder1\FolderA\,
07805.jpg,67466,9452d316,\Folder2\FolderB\,
```

Comment: `Except` is obviously some custom method and it looks simple because you simply have to call it, but what do you think is behind it? Indeed, `a very long and inefficient approach` as you put it. Programming isn't some sort of magic where you can use a single word for everything you want to do, you know.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: What makes you think the use of `Except` is very inefficient? It's likely to be building a `HashSet<string>` from `masterCsv`, them iterating over `myFullCsv`, yielding items which aren't in the set. How would you do it more efficiently than that?

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't mean to imply that it would be inefficient in terms of computational performance, I was just quoting a part of what the OP said to make it clear that there has to be a "long way" behind that method too, and that he probably does not understand the relativity of "long" in the context of file processing.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for efficient length of code primarily. But in my experience if the code is shorter it can also be a quicker computation, although I accept this is not always the case.

Comment: @SteveW LINQ can be deceiving in that way, one line of code can be equivalent to 10 or 20 in terms of computation depending on the expression, it is simply a more elegant and "functional" way to express queries on collections.  In the example Jon posted, it could be parsed out to a string array and a foreach loop doing comparisons and assigning matches to a pre-declared list.  Instead, LINQ gives you the ability to do it all in one line, which in my opinion, makes it much more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you *could* use:

```
var results = myFullCsv.Where(line => line.Split(',')[2] == targetValue)
                       .ToList();
```

That's just doing the "splitting and checking" you mention in the question but it's pretty simple code. It could be more efficient if you only consider as far as the third comma, but I wouldn't worry about that until it's proved to be a problem.

Personally I'd probably parse each line to an object with meaningful properties rather than treating is as a string, but that's probably what you mean by "the long way".

Note that this doesn't perform *any* validation, or try to handle escaped commas, or lines with fewer columns etc. Depending on your data source, you *may* need to make it a lot more robust.

Comment: Don't know how much more concise you can get than that!

Comment: This looks like just what I'm after. Will report back after testing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex. It doesn't require every line to have at least 3 elements. It doesn't allocate a string array for each line. Therefore it may be faster, but you'd have to test it to prove it.

```
var regex = new Regex("^.+?,.+?," + Regex.Escape(targetValue) + ",");
var results = myFullCsv.Where(l => regex.IsMatch(l)).ToList();
```